# Why is it assumed that would WW3 would be a nuclear war and what kind of conditions would have to be met to make it nuclear?

Tags: armed-conflict, international, nuclear-weapons

I'm curious as to why it's believed that WW3 would automatically be a full nuclear war instead of a conventional conflict. I understand the concept of MAD and a couple other Cold War policies but I don't understand how a ruling power could get to the level of desperation that it would be a viable option to plunge the world into radioactive oblivion. What kind of conditions would have to be met to justify launching nukes instead of suing for peace or trying other conventional strategies.

Comment: Justification for saying it would automatically be nuclear? Conventional weapons are very effective. Cyber and bio attacks are possibly more likely than nuclear. WWII bombing of Tokyo killed 100k with conventional, bombing of Hiroshima killed 80k and conventional has improved (?) since then.

Comment: You seem to be asking different questions in the title and body. The title is 'why is it assumed that ...?', while the body asks 'What kind of conditions would have to be met to <something else>'

Comment: "What kind of conditions would have to be met to justify launching nukes..." One (crazy) person with launch codes (Trump or Putin maybe) would be enough in principle.

Comment: Nuclear weapons are there, so why not use them? World wars are big, so the chance that all available kinds of weapons are used should be really big. In every conflict there is always at least one desperate side.

Comment: Even if Putin wanted to use Nukes if the Russians have a similar setup to ours it would require two people to actually launch them and that's assuming that certain people in Putin's Regime wouldn't have tried to stop him somehow. Sidenote: Stop letting Trump live rent free in your head he's been out of office for two years now.

Comment: Okay then two crazy guys would be the formal minimal requirements. And judging by what people vote for (or in case they don't live in a democrazy what they get) the chances for that to happen aren't low.

Comment: I don't think most people assume it would be nuclear. "I know not with what weapons World War III will be fought with...."

Comment: @Obie2.0  Nuclear warfare is a common theme for most WW3 scenarios so it's safe to say that most people do assume it would be.

Comment: "assumed" by whom ? "believed" by whom ? WW3 scenario written by whom ? (Hollywood ?) Can you at least reference a few sources that back that belief ? I am sure you can find some, even if I don't agree with you that it is shared by "most people"...

Comment: @doneal24 The reason that conventional bombing did more damage in WWII was that by the time the US had nukes available, all the "good" targets had already been bombed.

Comment: To corroborate the underlying assumption that it's believed that a new World War would include the use of nuclear weapons the question should cite at least one or more external sources for that belief. Also this question is basically equivalent to Cold War times thinking. During that times there were plans to fight a war with nuclear weapons, it just didn't happen, but maybe we were lucky. The question could maybe better explain what is the difference between the Cold War era and now (no clear superpowers, more nations with nuclear weapons?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **What is WWIII?**
  There are some who argue that the [Global War on Terrorísm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_terror) is a world war, but great powers did not fully mobilize and their sovereignty was never at stake. Something dubbed WWIII would have to involve some out of the US, China, or Russia, in some sort of [total war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_war).
- **Why would it go nuclear?**

  - **US vs. Russia**
    During much of the Cold War, NATO had inferior conventional forces in Europe. The US promised to go nuclear to defend western Europe, not just out of the goodness of their hearts but because otherwise they'd have to fight the Soviets *after* they incorporated European industrial potentials. Still, France and the UK got themselves nukes in case the US 'got wobbly' when push came to shove.
    To break this situation, NATO came up with the [AirLand Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirLand_Battle) concept to fight conventionally. Then the Warsaw Pact disappeared.
    Since then, Russia is in the situation that NATO used to have -- conventional inferiority. Their published [nuclear posture](https://www.sipri.org/commentary/blog/2020/russias-nuclear-doctrine-moves-focus-non-western-threats) envisions the use of nuclear weapons to prevent a conventional defeat.
  - **US vs. China**
    This one could more plausibly stay conventional, in my opinion. Neither power would invade the other, and the US security for *some* Asian allies is less firm than for their NATO partners. (Taiwan, notably.) But one could argue that a Sino-American conflict over Taiwan or the islands would not be a World War, for just that reason.

**So perhaps a tautology: if it doesn't go nuclear, it wasn't a World War.**

Comment: In these scenarios, using nuclear weapons is mostly defensive (to avoid defeat), because only if you have nothing left to lose then you can credibly threaten to destroy everything. Has the logic changed there since Cold War or is it basically still the same situation, only maybe with less clear superpowers?